# How to calculate the partial derivative of matrices' product

Tags: partial-derivative

Let $U = \frac{1}{2}u^TKu$,

then $\frac{\partial U}{\partial u} = Ku$.

How could I get this answer? Is there any book explains how to calculate derivative of matrices?

Comment: is $K$ symmetric?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By definition
$$
U=u^TKu=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{j=1}^n\sum_{i=1}^n K_{ij}u_iu_j.
$$
Differentiating with respect to the $l$-th element of $u$ we have
$$
2\frac{\partial U}{\partial u_l}=\sum_{j=1}^n K_{lj}u_j+\sum_{i=1}^n K_{il}u_i
$$
for all $l=1,\,\ldots,n$ and consequently
$$
\frac{\partial U}{\partial u}=\frac{1}{2}(Ku+K^Tu)=\frac{1}{2}(K+K^T)u
$$
If $K$ is symmetric, $K^T=K$ and
$$
\frac{\partial U}{\partial u}=Ku
$$

There are many books, for example

[Golub, Gene H., and Charles F. Van Loan, *Matrix Computations*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0801854148)